# How to make Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem work it should be in Windows Service?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-services, copy-paste

i trying to create auto copy application, once the USB Flashdisk plug in and then the service start copying.. I already done it with Windows Form application, and it work fine. When the service start copying, it pop out the copying dialog box.
BUT, when i implement Microsoft.VIsualBasic.FIlesystem in Windows Service application, it won't show the copying dialog box, it just COPY without any notification

here is my code

```
    private void BackupWithVisual()
    {
        sourceDir = "D:\\images";

        DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
        {
            if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                USBLocation = Drive.RootDirectory.ToString() + "Backup\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM") + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy");
            }
        }

        eventLog1.WriteEntry(USBLocation);


        Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceDir);

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(USBLocation))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(USBLocation);
        }

        FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourceDir, USBLocation, UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.DoNothing);
    }
```

in my last line of my code is where i use to do a copy with windows dialogbox just like we do CTRL + C then CTRL + V, in windows form application, it works very fine! but in windows service, the dialog box doesn't show, it just copy in the background, i already set my service to allow to interact with desktop. Is there something i missed?

Comment: a windows service "can´t" access the gui.

Comment: how about the feature that in logon tab writen "Allow service to interract with desktop"?

Comment: See [Why doesn't "Allow service to interact with desktop" work on Windows 8/7/Vista or Server 2012/2008?](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#InteractWithDesktop) in the Windows Services FAQ.

Comment: Mark question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your services runs under the LOCALSYSTEM account then you can check "Allow service to interact with desktop", for the benefit of legacy services that would fail if they could not show UI. But it won't help you anyway because the UI will show in session 0 where it is never seen!

You can read mor about session 0 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx